# Completely pausing a program using a DLL for debugging memory

Tags: debugging, memory, dll, pause

I want to be able to "pause" a program by using a DLL so I can debug an error as the memory of the program keeps getting instantly overwritten. I can attempt to do this by opening a console window and dragging/highlighting within it, which pauses the process completely. Is there a code approach to this which can mimic this behaviour? Code highlighting to pause is annoying as it is imprecise and a pain to do manually

Comment: Is it your program? If not, if you want to pause any other program, you can use a debugguer like https://www.cheatengine.org/. With it, you can pause the process, inspect its memory, its code...

Comment: I have to do it without using a debugger at all - is there an option to do something like manually add a breakpoint opcode that it will stop at? I'm not sure how flexible the program is with that

Comment: Why do you have to do it without a debugger?

Comment: The program has TlsCallbacks so attaching one is not an option and has memory debugger protection (at least cheat engine can't do it)